# Vim: Captue 'filetype command' state to variable?

Tags: vim, bundle

For vim users that use a bundle manager the docs typically say to use `filetype off` during init.

Is there a way to capture the current filetype command state to a variable so that I can restore it after the `filetype off` command and the bundle manager's init code has executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:redir` to capture the output of `:filetype`:

```
:redir => output
:filetype
:redir END
```

Then get the values with:

```
let [matchstr, detection, plugin, indent; _] = matchlist(output, 'detection:\(\S\+\)\s\+plugin:\(\S\+\)\s\+indent:\(\S\+\)')
```

Comment: Should that be `[matchstr, detection, plugin, indent; _]`? According to the help, the matched string is the first parameter.

Comment: Correct. I've updated the code. I always make that mistake with matchlist() and I'm left wondering what's wrong...